# Angular 2 - Can't access custom property

Tags: angular, attributes

I am using this package to have a drawing board (canvas) on my app, now what i'm trying to do is create dynamic canvas and have the data (text in canvas) filled from the database, what i'm trying to do is having a custom property data-content containing the text of the canvas like this :

```
  <div *ngFor="let c of loc.content.data">
    <div *ngIf="c.container == 'Canvas'">
        <canvas-whiteboard [attr.content]="c.subject"  #canvasWhiteboard [drawButtonClass]="'fa fa-pencil'" [clearButtonClass]="'fa fa-eraser'" [batchUpdateTimeoutDuration]="10"
        (onBatchUpdate)="sendBatchUpdate($event)" (onClear)="onCanvasClear()">
      </canvas-whiteboard>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The reference to my canvas is done like this :

```
@ViewChild('canvasWhiteboard') canvas: CanvasWhiteboardComponent;
```

Then in the ngAfterViewInit i'm trying to access those [attr.content] to write the text, but when I use getAttribute("content") i get :

> Property 'getAttribute' does not exist on type
>   'CanvasWhiteboardComponent'.

I understand that since getAttribute is an "ElementRef" method, so i decided to switch to that by modifying the type of canvas from CanvasWhiteboardComponent to ElementRef, but when I do that i can no longer access to the canvas's context because ElementRef returns a DOM reference that doesn't contain the context, so I have to stick with the canvas declared as CanvasWhiteboardComponent.
So how do i access "CanvasWhiteboardComponent" custom attributes ? Thanks everyone

Comment: First of all you have several instances, then to get ElementRef you should use `read` option on `ViewChildren`. And getAttribute is not ElementRef property but rather `elRef.nativeElement.getAttribute`

Comment: @yurzui I actually have only one instance of the canvas, (there is only 1 data on the db), i'm leaving the multiple instances for later, and i did use the read option on ViewChild (since i have only 1 instance) but I couldn't access to the context property of the canvas

Comment: Use other query for `ElementRef`

Comment: @yurzui How's that ?

Comment: `@ViewChild('canvasWhiteboard', { read: ElementRef }) canvasElRef: ElementRef;`

Comment: But you have access to that attribute `loc.content.data[0].subject`

Comment: @yurzui That's exactly what i did, but i can't get the canvas context like this : 
`this.canvasElRef.nativeElement.context` , this gives an error, (context doesn't exist on that element), plus i can't get access to the `CanvasWhiteBoardComponent` properties and methods such `generateCanvasDataUrl`

Comment: As i said you should use two queries, one for CanvasWhiteboardComponent and one for ElementRef

Comment: `@ViewChild('canvasWhiteboard', { read: ElementRef }) canvasElRef: ElementRef; @ViewChild('canvasWhiteboard') canvas: CanvasWhiteboardComponent;` and then `this.canvasElRef.nativeElement.getAttribute` and `this.canvas.context`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157167/discussion-between-soufiane-touil-and-yurzui).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@yurzui 's suggestion of using two queries solved it !
One query for the CanvasWhiteBoardComponent to get the context and other stuffs, and the other query for the ElementRef to get access to the attributes :)